# replacing page content with .html(content) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird problem in jQuery. The problem is that I can smoothly use `$('#container').html(content)` to replace the page content but to specific page. It is not working all around. Gives 'TypeError' message in console. Is there any probability that using SlickGrid can cause such error. Because error is thrown only in that pages where I have used SlickGrid.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to reconstruct your problem in jsfiddle.net. "TypeError" you will get, if element with that ID you have selected, doesn't exist or you have syntax problems in code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's going on with your page, but my guess is that you may have a conflict with the `$` between jQuery and SlickGrid.  Look at the [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function in jQuery - it may help you out.

Call `$.noConflict();` before SlickGrid's javascript `<script>` tag is added, and then refer to jQuery functions by using `jQuery(selector)` instead of `$(selector)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think there is conflict because other methods such as fadeIn, or fadeOut just works fine to given element. The only problem is with .html()